# Mongoose Architecture to add a document and update another document with the ID of the first

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

More of a general question. I'm setting up a Mongoose Node back end. I have 3 collections, User, Department and Activity.

If I add an Activity, I get the newly created Activity's _ID. I then need to add that ID to the appropriate Users array of activities and add the activity to the correct department.

Just wondering what the architecture for this should be. I've got my endpoints set up using Express. And an ActivityController and User/Department controller. Which add, get, update and destroy Activities/Users/Departments.

When I add an Activity I'm effecting a document in the other 2 collections though so how would I set this up... would `create` in the Activity controller also update User and Department as well? Or should I have a controller sitting on top of them all? I'm not really sure.

Activity Schema:

```
activityName: String
activityOwner: ObjectId
activityLocation: String
```

Department Schema:

```
departmentName: String
departmentActivities: [ObjectId]
```

User Schema:

```
userName: String
userAddress: String
userActivities: [ObjectId]
```

Comment: would be better if you provide the schema for all of them.

Comment: @cagliostro I've provided a basic schema. Enough to understand the problem. If i add an activity I need to update the User and Department with the ID of the activity. How would I do that in terms of Controllers handling HTTP rest requests.. what kind of architecture. E.g to add a single activity without updating anyother collection I would simply: Endpoint>Activity Controller>Model>Db

Comment: To answer simply I will say that the best is to use the Post Save mongoose hook in your model . But I think that you can probably find a best overall db schema. As it misses some information of relation between all models it's hard to recommend something. At least you ca add an department ID in your activity Schema and remove the activity array in your department Model. In fact probably the same for users.